# Billing v3 IabHelper class triggers nullpointerexception

Tags: android

Ive implemented in-app billing, but Im having an issue where the app crashes with a nullpointerexception when consuming a purchase.

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 6121): java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime( 6121):    at com.test.my.app.util.IabHelper.consume(IabHelper.java:660)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6121):    at com.test.my.app.util.IabHelper$3.run(IabHelper.java:953)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6121):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

In IabHelper line 660 we find this:

```
if (!itemInfo.mItemType.equals(ITEM_TYPE_INAPP)) { //Crash happens here
            throw new IabException(IABHELPER_INVALID_CONSUMPTION,
                    "Items of type '" + itemInfo.mItemType + "' can't be consumed.");
        }
```

Any ideas whats causing this?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the purchase your are consuming is not null, for instance:

```
public void consumeItem(String SKU, IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener listener){
    Purchase purchase = mInventory.getPurchase(SKU);
    if(purchase!=null) {
        mHelper.consumeAsync(purchase, listener);
    }
}
```